# fake path in extjs 4 in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extjs4

I work with extjs 4

when I use this code :

```
 {
                xtype: 'filefield',
                id: 'file1',
                fieldLabel: 'test1',
                labelWidth: 100,
                msgTarget: 'side',
                allowBlank : false,
                anchor: '100%',
                buttonText: 'test'
            },
```

and when I use chrome  I have this label in this composant :

```
c:\fakepath\.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filefield with extjs 4.2 without fakepath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302841/filefield-with-extjs-4-2-without-fakepath)

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely expected behavior. I would suggest googling "chrome fakepath" to understand why this is happening, why it's expected, and why it's not a problem.